# How to disable guzzle caching in behat.yml for goutte driver using behat/mink?

Tags: behat, mink, goutte, guzzle

Is there a configuration parameter that completely disables guzzle caching in the goutte driver using behat/mink?
None of the following behat.yml parameters had an effect in my env:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            goutte:
                guzzle_parameters:
                    cache.ttl: 0
                    cache.adapter: Guzzle\Common\Cache\NullCacheAdapter
                    cache.provider: null
```

Comment: Guzzle only caches responses if you attach a CachePlugin to a client. This is not done by default when using Goutte.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I assumed that it caches because it sends an If-Modified-Since header on a second request. In this case the tested application sends a 304 Not modified response header without a response body and mink has nothing to parse. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the If-Modified_since header. The only additional header I see is Set-Cookie.

Comment: @t3node, actually I am also not able to reproduce it in a pure test setup but I have randomly failing behat tests in Jenkins with a message like this: 'The string "searchstring" was not found anywhere in the HTML response of the current page.

+--[ HTTP/1.1 304 | http://testhost/test | GoutteDriver ]'

I try to find a test setup that reproduces this behaviour.